# Creating a persistent life counter for a facebook game

Tags: javascript, facebook, actionscript-3

i am currently working on a facebook game and i have a problem concerning the integration of a life counter which regenerates over time for a facebook game.

The game is a simple Flash/AS3 shooter in which users are competing for the highest score.

For monetary reasons every game costs one life and users should only be able to start a new game, if said life counter is >=1.

To clear things up, i submitted a link to Popcap's facebook game "Zuma Blitz":

[ZUMA Blitz](http://apps.facebook.com/zumablitz/?fb_source=bookmarks_apps&ref=bookmarks&count=0&fb_bmpos=3_0)

I can think of a few ways to do this, but i don't know which is the best/easiest approach.

Would it be best to:

1. Make it in AS3 with server communication via php?
2. Or do it in JavaScript and communicate the count back to AS3?

Another maybe related question is, how do i tell my database that the data from the life counter should be stored when the game is closed (for example by closing the browser).

Can i do this from Flash or do i have to apply a html/JavaScript method?

Comment: I Believe that your question get down voted because is kind jumbled. Try make it more clear, maybe you will get better results/responses. +1 because nobody said WHY they down voted you.

Comment: I agree, it isn't a bad question just some wild wording. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 1. **Whenever you can**, use ActionScript for communicating with the server. URLLoader and URLRequestMethod, as jhocking said, are the way to go.

**Whenever you can't** do something with ActionScript, ExternalInterface provides you all JavaScript power.

For the game closing event (browser tab closing event), you can interface with JavaScript like this:

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
// ...
ExternalInterface.addCallback("closeGame", tellDatabaseToStore);
// ...
public function tellDatabaseToStore():void{
// ...
}
```

In JavaScript:

```
window.onbeforeunload = clean_up;
function clean_up()
{
   var flash = document.${application} || window.${application};
   flash.closeGame();
}
```

`${application}` should be substituted with `["YourEmbeddedFlashElementName"]`.

Comment: STALTZ... totally awesome thank you so much! That was exactly what i was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with option 1. I mean, you certainly *could* use ExternalInterface to communicate between JavaScript and ActionScript, and then have the JavaScript relay the message to your server, but it's simpler to just make a POST query from ActionScript.

Look up information about URLLoader and URLRequestMethod.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply! But if i do it this way, how can i tell the server when the application gets closed and the last data should be stored?